# How to create a new instance or hand over an existing one when using Bloc or Cubit in the Go_Router package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

Flutter Question

You are about to go from page A to page B.
Create CubitA as a BlockProvider, and put page B in child.
In B, go to page C with CubitA. (Use BlockProvider.value)
But sometimes I have to move from C to page B. At this point, it moves with an existing instance of CubitA.

It's a question.
When you go to B, in certain situations (A->B), you create an instance of CubitA
In another specific situation (C -> B), I would like to deliver an instance of CubitA.

How do I make a GoRoute in this situation?

There are two ways I thought of it.

1. Make 2 GoRoute.
2. Inside GoRoute, wrap the builder with try{}catch(e){} and try{} In the section, it executes logic to load the existing instance, and when an error occurs, it goes to catch{} to create a new instance.
3. None..

I would appreciate it if you could suggest a new method if it's not number 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

If all three pages dependes on same `Bloc` or `Cubit` you can use top level `BlocProvider` above the router. Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(create: (context) => SomeCubit(), child: App());
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({super.key});
  final _router = GoRouter(routes: [
    GoRoute(path: '/', builder: (context, state) => const Home(), routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: 'A',
        builder: (context, state) => PageA(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: 'B',
        builder: (context, state) => PageB(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: 'C',
        builder: (context, state) => PageC(),
      ),
    ])
  ]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to create an instance only when I enter a specific page. What should I do then?

Comment: Do you wanna use same instance for all pages or different instance for each of them? What's your use case?

Comment: I made a bloc that manages pages about membership. This bloc shares the same instance on multiple pages required for sign up, but I want to delete the instance as soon as I leave the membership sector. So that I can get a new instance later when I get back into the sign up sector